# Any way to reuse result from N Unit test in another test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, integration-testing

I know the obvious answer here is to use [SetUp] but there is a very real chance that the code that gets the result could throw an exception and we want to test that.

Disclaimer up front, we are not doing "true" unit tests. What we are making could best be described as integration tests, the design is done, we did not make unit tests up front, we don't have the resources to make them now, but we are trying to get some automatic coverage on a larger chunks of functionality.

One such chunk is a function that aggregates data from an external database and creates 4 complex objects that have various references to each other that we then store in several tables in our internal database. We have already refactored the main aggregation function to return the objects in a wrapper class (before the aggregation function was doing the inserting as well). The caller now does the inserting, this let us write automated tests to validate the data automatically without the complexity of pulling it back out of our database.

The problem is that in NUnit, we want to test this Aggregation function. We can not make it any more granular. But we want to validate each of the 4 objects separately as well as verify that the function doesn't throw any exceptions.

The function takes quite awhile to run with even a small set so we'd like to avoid rerunning the same thing 4 different times to test each object.

Ideally we'd like to run a test on verifying that the function completes with no errors->feed that result into validation for one complex object->complex object-> and so on. Is this possible with NUnit or perhaps there is another paradigm we can use?

I suppose in the worst case, we just run the Aggregation on the same dataset 4 times.

Comment: What's the issue with using a Setup? If there is an exception in the setup then the test will not be run and the error tells you that the setup failed because of exception XYZ. If an object was expensive to create I would cache it in a field for other tests to use.

Comment: Granted, we're already playing it fast and loose with N Unit, but my understanding was that you shouldn't "test" the [Setup].

Comment: Create a class level variable in the test class to hold the value. As a disclaimer, this makes the tests dependent on the order that they are run, which under normal testing scenarios is a bad idea (unit tests should be stand alone and not dependent on anything outside the test to run). If it were me in your case I'd make the variable nullable so I could easily test to see if the previous test had indeed been run and throw an Assert.Inconclusive if not.

Comment: I think the order dependencies are fine, in fact that's what I've been looking into in the time since I've posted this. I'm not fooling myself into thinking these are unit tests so I'm ok with it. If it's null, then the aggregation failed for sure, no reason to try to validate the individual object enumerations.

Comment: I realize your understanding of what you are doing, I put in the disclaimer primarily for others reading this post.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your hesitation with doing tests in the setup and it certainly isn't appropriate for most unit-testing situations. However, sometimes it's useful and NUnit supports it. An assertion failure in a setup will cause the fixture to fail and all the test methods to be reported as failures as well.

[FWIW, what NUnit does **not** support is failure in a teardown Any exception in teardown, even SuccessException, causes an error.]

NUnit has a few tests of it's own that are more functional than unit tests and that use this pattern. The somewhat costly loading of an assembly is done once in the OneTimeSetUp. A few assertions validate that the setup ran correctly. Then various independent tests are run against  the assembly that was loaded.

You could easily do the same thing, running the Aggregation function in your OneTimeSetUp and having four different tests to check the various aspects.

Stylisticly, I see nothing  wrong with this way of testing, so long as it's not the only kind of testing you do for the function. If it's important, it probably deserves some unit tests as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you not doing "real" unit tests already, why not just create a single "wrapper" test case that calls a set of "steps" in sequence like:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldPassAllTests()
{
    var result1 = Step1();
    var result2 = Step2(result1);
    var result3 = Step3(result2);
    Step4(result3);
}

private void Step1/2/3/4()
{
    // Arrange Something
    // Do Something
    // Assert Something
}
```

Its definitely not ideal but at least you are making sure your tests will run in the correct sequence.

If you ask me I would try instead of resorting to things like this I would try to push for some time to try to refactor your code into something more testable and write proper tests from the start.